# Cartoon about 4 kids going into a digital world and fighting with an army

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

There was this one cartoon that I can't remember the name to, but this is how it went: There were 4 kids, and they had some sort of magic talismans that would transport them to a digital world, and here they would fight in a war with troops on their side and the enemy side, and the villain had a few generals that had better powers, and every episode he would send one or more of them. They would die, but they would then come back a few episodes later, because the villain had this thing that made them respawn.

The main characters would have to fight every episode until they realized that they could destroy that respawn thing. And that's how the last few episodes went. I can't remember the name, but I want to rewatch the series, so does anyone know what this is?

It’s not *Code Lyoko* or *Di-Gata Defenders*.

Comment: If it's the same as the one I'm thinking of, then it turned up in the UK with voice-overs in the early 1990s - was that when you saw it or a different time?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: It was aired on a channel that was made in 2008, and I’m pretty sure it had 3D animation like code lyoko, so it’s probably not that

Comment: @The Overseer - Which channel did it air on? And can you describe the appearance (hair colour/style, clothing, ethnicity, etc) and sex of the four kids? Also, how did the kids fight? Did they have powers, or special weapons, or control monsters?

Comment: It aired on a Serbian channel named Ultra, but I think that was translated form some other language. All I know is that at least one of them was a girl. I think that they used both weapons and powers, and they were inside robo suits with visors on their eyes, like the power rangers. All of their suits were different color, like red, blue, green and stuff. They controlled their own army, with generals and stuff, like in a real war. The enemy leader had his generals, and he had this piece of code programmed into the game they were in that made his troops respawn. It was also what the main…

Comment: …Characters used to come back every episode after they die. Basically in the finale, they destroyed that code, but it also meant that if they get killed they would be back in the normal world, but would not be able to go back and fight, and their talisman thing would be broken.

Comment: @The Overseer - Thanks for responding. These are useful clarifications. Can you also confirm roughly _when_ you watched this show? Also, was the entire show animated, or were there any parts of it in live-action? And were the kids originally  regular school kids from present day Earth, or did they always live in some other fantasy world?